# Use of regular expression in the Blue Prism Application Modeller

Tags: regex, rpa, sap-gui, blueprism

I am using Blue Prism 5 to automate a task in SAP GUI. I found that visually the same control on one of the screens spies with different IDs. Looking at those IDs gives me the suspicion that the SAP client is actually displaying different fields at that point, but to my task that is logically equivalent.

An examples of this are these three IDs, all spied from the same place on a dialog displaying a city name, but for different people's addresses:

```
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_RIGHT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1000/ssubSCREEN_1000_WORKAREA_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1100/ssubSCREEN_1100_MAIN_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1101/tabsGS_SCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP/tabpSCREEN_1100_TAB_01/ssubSCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUSS:0028/ssubGENSUB:SAPLBUSS:7016/subA05P01:SAPLBUA0:0400/subADDRESS:SAPLSZA7:0600/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA7:0601/ctxtADDR2_DATA-CITY1
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_RIGHT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1000/ssubSCREEN_1000_WORKAREA_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1100/ssubSCREEN_1100_MAIN_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1101/tabsGS_SCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP/tabpSCREEN_1100_TAB_01/ssubSCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUSS:0028/ssubGENSUB:SAPLBUSS:7016/subA05P01:SAPLBUA0:0400/subADDRESS:SAPLSZA7:0600/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA7:0601/txtADDR2_DATA-CITY1
/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/subSCREEN_3000_RESIZING_AREA:SAPLBUS_LOCATOR:2036/subSCREEN_1010_RIGHT_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1000/ssubSCREEN_1000_WORKAREA_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1100/ssubSCREEN_1100_MAIN_AREA:SAPLBUPA_DIALOG_JOEL:1101/tabsGS_SCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP/tabpSCREEN_1100_TAB_01/ssubSCREEN_1100_TABSTRIP_AREA:SAPLBUSS:0028/ssubGENSUB:SAPLBUSS:7016/subA05P01:SAPLBUA0:0400/subADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/ctxtADDR1_DATA-CITY1
```

As you can see, they are mostly the same and only differ near the end.

I think this is an opportunity for using a regular expression in the Blue Prism Application Modeler. So I tried configuring it as such. The result is in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from Blue Prism Object Studio]

I obviously tried several flavors of RegExpr and variations on the expression, but I could not get it to find that control.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Is it the expression-syntax or am I misunderstanding the RegExpr-feature here completely?

My workaround is spying each variant separately and having a wait stage that looks for all of them.

Thanks for reading and I would be grateful for any advice on this.

Comment: To be clear, you want to get **ctxtADDR2_DATA-CITY1** , **txtADDR2_DATA-CITY1** and **ctxtADDR1_DATA-CITY1** or just **ctxtADDR1, txtADDR2, ctxtADDR2***?

Comment: try `c*txtADDR\d_DATA-CITY1`

Comment: Did you try using wildcard? The expression would be `*DATA-CITY*`. Any why did you uncheck the ComponentType? Also you should upgrade to 6 if you can, 5 is kinda old now.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the regex mode does not work in SAP.

I believe you're workaround is correct and that's something that I would suggest in that situation.

Alternative is to connect to SAP API using coding stages, but it's a complex matter.